# How to merge two dictionaries task and only keep matching keys

Tags: python, dictionary

Write a program in which, based on two
dictionaries a new dictionary is created. Into this new
the dictionary will include those elements that are represented in each of the source dictionaries (meaning the keys of the elements). The values of the elements in the dictionary being created are
sets of the values of the corresponding elements in the source dictionaries

example:

```
dictionary_1 = {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
dictionary_2 = {1: 10, 2: 20, 30: 30}
final_dictionaries = {1: {1, 10}, 2: {2, 20}}
```

my code:

```
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}
for i in range(int(input())):
    dict1[input("> ")] = input()
print(dict1)
for i in range(int(input())):
    dict2[input("> ")] = input()
print(dict2)
```

yes, it is not finished yet, I don’t know what to do next

Comment: Iterate over each key in dict1.  If that key is also present in dict2, make a set of that key's elements in both dicts and assign to dict3.

Comment: Also, as a purely practical suggestion, I would hardcode dict1 and dict2 in your program, as shown in the example.  Building from user input takes much longer, and you will get frustrated if you have to run the program more than a few times.

Comment: for future reference, don't include code with a ton of `input`s, since it makes it harder for others to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dict comprehensions, loop over keys in the first dict, only include it if the key is also in the second, and use a set of both values as the value in the new dict.

```py
d1 = {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
d2 = {1: 10, 2: 20, 30: 30}
d3 = {k: {d1[k], d2[k]} for k in d1 if k in d2}
```

Answer (score 2):

A dict comprehension using the intersection of their keys will do:

```
d1 = {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
d2 = {1: 10, 2: 20, 30: 30}
    
final_d = {k: {d1[k], d2[k]} for k in d1.keys() & d2.keys()}
# {1: {1, 10}, 2: {2, 20}}
```